# Where to find swagger.json for Contenta CMS

Tags: npm, drupal, swagger

Hello I have installed Contenta CMS from here: https://github.com/contentacms/contenta_jsonapi along with the contentajs package from here: https://github.com/contentacms/contentajs I would like to access the api through swagger. I have used npm install http-server and downloaded swagger which shows me the default petstore app at http://localhost:8080. How do I change the swagger output to the Contenta app? The contenta cms is installed in http://mycontenta.com on my local machine